# Post Async without Redirecting in Razor Pages Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to make a social networking app, where users can react to posts. But every time someone reacts I need to be able to post the reaction directly to the model without redirecting.

Here is my code so far (with redirecting):

Model:

```
[BindProperty]
public Models.Table Table { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostReactAsync(int t)
{
    var reaction = new Models.Table
    {
         Reaction = Table.Reaction,
         PostId = t,
         UserName = _userManager.GetUserName(User)
    };
    _context.Table.Add(reaction);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Redirect("./Index");
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="t" value="@item.ID" class="form-control" style="display:none;" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Table.Reaction" id="@item.ID x" type="radio" value="true" onclick="document.getElementById('cal').click()" />
        <label class="r good" for="@item.ID x"></label>
        <input asp-for="Table.Reaction" id="@item.ID y" type="radio" value="false" onclick="document.getElementById('cal').click()" />
        <label class="r bad" for="@item.ID y"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="cal" asp-page-handler="React" value="submit" style="display:none;" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use AJAX or some other method of sending data to a server that doesn't involve navigating a page.

Comment: use AJAX + API style instead of regular controller style

Comment: Yes, you need to make an AJAX request, instead of a traditional form post, and your action should return an `ObjectResult` instead of a redirect, with something your client-side code can utilize to determine the result of the request. That could be as simple as just passing back something like `new { success = [true/false] }`. You'll need need something in your AJAX callback to process this response and update the UI accordingly to notify the user that their reaction was in fact saved (or not).